# Convert to Roman Numeral!

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, roman-numerals

Your task is to convert a given **positive integer** from Arabic numeral to Roman numeral.

Things get difficult when you count to 4000.

The romans did this by adding a line above a symbol to multiply that symbol by `1 000`. However, overlines aren't exactly displayable in ASCII. Also, there are double overlines to multiply a symbol by `1 000 000`, and then triple overline to multiply a symbol by `1 000 000 000`, etc...

Therefore, I decided to use **parentheses** to replace overlines.

The symbols can be **individually** placed in parentheses. For example, both `(VI)` and `(V)(I)` are valid representations of `6 000`. `(V)M` is also a valid representation of 6000.

`(I)` is a valid way to represent `1 000`.

#### Testcases

```
Input: 1
Output: I
Input: 2
Output: II
Input: 3
Output: III
Input: 4
Output: IV
Input: 15
Output: XV
Input: 40
Output: XL
Input: 60
Output: LX
Input: 67
Output: LXVII
Input: 400
Output: CD
Input: 666
Output: DCLXVI
Input: 3000
Output: MMM
Input: 3999
Output: MMMCMXCIX
Input: 4000
Output: M(V)
Input: 4999
Output: M(V)CMXCIX
Input: 6000
Output: (VI)
Input: 6000000
Output: ((VI))
Input: 6006000
Output: ((VI)VI)
Input: 6666666666
Output: (((VI)DCLXVI)DCLXVI)DCLXVI
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest code in bytes win.

Comment: The justification for why this isn't a duplicate clutters the spec. It would be better without it IMO.

Comment: Where would I add the justification?

Comment: Leave it out. If someone questions whether or not it is a duplicate, have the discussion in comments or in chat.

Comment: @Mego Done. :-)

Comment: Is `(IV)` an acceptable representation of 4000?

Comment: Yes, clarified.

Comment: @Neil For that case, you can output which one you want, 'cause `(IV)` and `MMMM` are the same length in bytes.

Comment: @ErikKonstantopoulos Not really. `MMMM` is not accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Roman numeral converter function](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/797/roman-numeral-converter-function)

Comment: @mbomb007 That's the opposite direction.

Answer (score 10):

### Mathematica, 67 bytes

```
Fold["("<>#<>")"<>#2&,RomanNumeral[#~IntegerDigits~1000]/."N"->""]&
```

Avoids all trouble with `M` by converting the input to base 1000 and converting each digit separately with `RomanNumeral`. Then we fold them up by inserting `(...)` from the left.

Unfortunately, Mathematica represents zeros as `N` so we need to get rid of those.

Comment: darn mathematica with its builtins for everything >:(

Comment: @OldBunny2800 I'd be surprised if this wasn't beaten by any of the golfing languages anyway though.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 And it costs real money to get it. That's bad.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I thought simply `RomanNumeral` can do it?

Comment: @KennyLau It outputs `MMMM` for `4000`, it only starts working to spec at `5000` (and then you get the same problem for `4000000` etc.). Even then, it uses overbars instead of parentheses. If you're fine with that, you should say so in the challenge specification.

Answer (score 9):

### JavaScript (ES6), 136 bytes

```
f=n=>n<4e3?"M1000CM900D500CD400C100XC90L50XL40X10IX9V5IV4I1".replace(/(\D+)(\d+)/g,(_,r,d)=>r.repeat(n/d,n%=d)):`(${f(n/1e3)})`+f(n%1e3)
```

For numbers under 4000, repeats each Roman "letter" as many times as possible, using the list of Roman "letters" and their decimal values. Otherwise recursively builds up the answer from the division and modulo with 1000. Fortunately `repeat` truncates so I don't have to do it myself.

Answer (score 5):

### Common Lisp, 108

```lisp
(defun p(n)(if(> n 0)(if(< n 4000)(format()"~@R"n)(format()"(~A)~@[~A~]"(p(floor n 1000))(p(mod n 1000))))))
```

### Ungolfed

```lisp
(defun p(n)
  (if (> n 0)
      (if (< n 4000)

          ;; Built-in Roman formatter (between 1 and 3999)
          (format () "~@R" n)

          ;; Divide N by 1000, as 1000*Q + R.
          ;; First print (p Q) in parentheses (recursively)
          ;; Then, if it is not NIL, the remainder R.
          (format () "(~A)~@[~A~]"
                  (p (floor n 1000))
                  (p (mod n 1000))))))
```

### Tests

Two tests give different outputs than the ones from the question:

```lisp
(loop for (in out) in '((1 "I")
                        (2 "II")
                        (3 "III")
                        (4 "IV")
                        (15 "XV")
                        (40 "XL")
                        (60 "LX")
                        (67 "LXVII")
                        (400 "CD")
                        (666 "DCLXVI")
                        (3000 "MMM")
                        (3999 "MMMCMXCIX")
                        (4000 "M(V)")
                        (4999 "M(V)CMXCIX")
                        (6000 "(VI)")
                        (6000000 "((VI))")
                        (6006000 "((VI)VI)")
                        (6666666666 "(((VI)DCLXVI)DCLXVI)DCLXVI"))
   for computed = (p in)
   unless (string= out computed)
   collect (list in out computed))

=> ((4000 "M(V)" "(IV)")
    (4999 "M(V)CMXCIX" "(IV)CMXCIX"))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>137</s> <s>134</s> <s>130</s> 129 bytes

Recursive function that returns the string. I'm trying to golf down the numeral encodings a bit more if possible, but I'm not sure how.

Whoops, it's practically a direct port of @Neil's ES6 answer now.

```ruby
f=->x{(x<t=1e3)?"CM900D500CD400C100XC90L50XL40X10IX9V5IV4I1".gsub(/(\D+)(\d+)/){s=x/v=eval($2);x%=v;$1*s}:"(#{f[x/t]})#{f[x%t]}"}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY7BasJAEIbv-xQhRtitxMy6m7RbG3tILgFLbxLQIrUmKtgqzSbdEnLwOXrJoX0o36a7mmH45-Nn_mF-fj_L1Xfb_pUyd-_Opzx0J6rG6kGGNGPk0Y6eBEDsA0Qx10IB0kjA1Id0yiGlkKRi5icznlB7uCnKFfbwIh4QvFgPiEfqIlReFWbV6x47IzJW_bAaO_SmaO5t3KvzufLkS0Mu1NdkN90j7Gu722fWJpMFso6lLCy7VzvL4dv28H5sLHdimYw25GG50zmUfayv0fb8TNEIMcQR9REHFOi-1aBHECAGGpgQwjiAuKHAkJFumjbLXV3v_gM)

Comment: An anonymous user has suggested a golf: `{v=$2.to_i;s=x/v;x%=v;$1*s}` to `{s=x/(v=eval$2);x%=v;$1*s}` (saves 1 byte).

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>185 161</s> 144 bytes

```
r=->i{i>(t=1e3)? "(#{r[i/t]})"+r[i%t]:(s=?I*i;"IVXXLCCDM".scan(/(.)(.)(.)/){|x,y,z|{x*5=>y,x*4=>x+y,y*2=>z,y+x+y=>x+z}.map{|x,y|s.gsub!x,y}};s)}
```

Over a year after the original post, I think I learned something about golfing.

<sub>Thank you Value Ink for your valuable comments.</sub>

Comment: `gsub` can take a string as the first argument, removing the need for substitutions into a regex pattern since `s.gsub! x,y` does it automatically. Other than that, you can probably just forgo the assignment of your `a` array since you only use it once, and put it directly into the `each_slice` call.

Comment: `"IVXXLCCDM".scan(/(.)(.)(.)/){|x,b,c|...` works too

Comment: Also `r[x]` is functionally equivalent to `r.(x)` whenever stabby lambdas are involved

Comment: @ValueInk thank you. That `r[x]` trick is going to be useful for all my futer recursive golf in ruby!

Comment: Hi sorry to ask so late, but is there a way instead of doing (III), to do MMM?

Comment: @DialFrost Replacing `i>(t=1e3)` with `i>=4*(t=1e3)` would do that.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 134

```
m=1000;x=scan();while(x[1]>=m)x=c(floor(x[1]/m),x[1]%%m,x[-1]);cat(rep("(",length(x)),sep="");cat(as.character(as.roman(x)),sep=")")
```

It's pretty much not the best option, but I think the idea should go pretty similar to this.

Answer (score 2):

### TCL 134 bytes

```
proc f r {
set map {M 1000+ CM 900+ D 500+ CD 400+ C 100+ XC 90+ L 50+ XL 40+ X 10+ IX 9+ V 5+ IV 4+ I 1+}
expr [string map $map $r]0}
```

Try it here: https://rextester.com/BJC92885

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 188 <s>194</s>

*-6 bytes from getting rid of some whitespace*

This challenge brought me back to when I was first learning to program...

```
def f(x,s=zip("M CM D CD C XC L XL X IX V IV I".split(),[1e3,900,500,400,100,90,50,40,10,9,5,4,1])):
 r=""if x<4e3else"("+f(x/1e3)+")";x%=1e3
 for a,b in s:
    while x>=b:r+=a;x-=b
 return r
```

It might not be the shortest solution, but I had fun golfing this problem.

[Try it out!](https://repl.it/CHJj/2)